# Paste in visual block mode without deleting the character under vertically multiple cursor

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-block

When I want to paste some text after selecting vertically with `<C-q>`

[image]

It is known that Vim/gVim will replace the character under the cursor. For example, below is shown the result after pasting `hello` using `"+P` after `<C-q>`.

[image]

It is shown how the first column is being 'replaced'.

Is there some option to avoid this behavior instead of manually inserting a space to the selection and then re-select and paste?

PS: I know that in this particular example I could insert the text using `s` command, but my question is for a general use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is the normal behavior of `p` and `P` in all visual modes. It is the only desirable behavior, actually, and it happens to match how more familiar editors work:

- you select the text you want to "paste over",
- you "paste over" the selected text.

If that's not what you want to happen, then use a more appropriate command. In this case (assuming you want to prepend the content of the register to the selected text):

```
I<C-r>" <Esc>
```

[image: hw]

Comment: That's great using `<C-r>+` in my case ! Pasting using `"+P` after `<C-q>I` brakes the mode and the pasted text is not propagated to the rest of lines. Using `<C-r>+` works like a sharm. I finally setup `inoremap <silent> <nowait> <C-Space> <C-r>+`  (Space is near the v) to easily do the pasting without breaking the mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another option: get a range for the insertion (in this case, I'd probably use `vip:`), then do

```
:[range]substitute/^/\=@+
```

(abbreviate the `:substitute` to `:s` as desired).

As pointed out, if you need to manipulate the result of the paste further you need string concatenation (or other VimScript expressions); for simple things, I would probably use the `I<C-r>=` method. An abbreviated example with a space after the paste:

```
:s/^/\=@+..' '
```

Comment: missing a space?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt do you mean you want `\=@+ .. ' '`? You could; the OP isn't clear about the desired results

Comment: oh I thought, that was his question. but yes, something along those lines

Comment: I explicitly written that in this particular case I know I can insert the yanked text with the substitute command, and I was interested in a general case, so when the columns are not at the first one `^`, but, for example, are indented... Pasting without overwriting the character under cursor (which is what `p` and/or `P do)` is useful when coding.

Comment: Maybe other readers will appreciate this answer. I do. BTW, to allow for indented lines, use e.g. `[range]:s/\s*\zs/\=@+`. Just the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @romainl works fine as long as the buffer contains a normal selection. If it is containing a block selection I would do: `1v5>PgvloWhd`

Where:

- `1v` select a block of the shape of your clipboard
- `5>` make enough room to insert the block
- `P` paste the block
- `gvloWh` select the not necessary white spaces
- `d` delete them

This assume that the first line of the block is made of one WORD